# How exactly are the Einstein analystics external connectors secured?

Tags: security, einstein-analytics

I'm trying to connect einstein analytics to one of our local data servers. But network wont add the whitelist until they know how does this connection stay secure?

And luckily for me not a single line of text in any salesforce document related to analytics or its external connectors covers security.

edit: local SAP HANA OData-based connector

Comment: This depends on the data source. What are you connecting to?

Comment: @identigral HANA

Comment: It's username/password over HTTPS: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_integrate_connectors_sap_hana_settings.htm&type=5

Comment: thats what i thought, just had to make sure